# Convert json to corresponding HashMap

Tags: java, json, performance, parsing, gson

When converting json to Map using gson, we are having instance of LinkedTreeMap with all values String or Boolean... even numbers are converted to String...

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Map<String, Object> result = gson.fromJson(EXAMPLE, new TypeToken<Map<String,Object>>() {}.getType());
```

How do we convert json to simplest HashMap with corresponding primitive wrappers? Also performance is very important in this case... I want to create as less garbage as possible and resuse parsers...

Is there a way to do that using gson? or any other lib?

Please dont suggest to create special java types for each json... I'll rather navigate trough map...

Here is an example

```
{                           // Hashmap (as no ordering or sorting is essential)
  "bool": true,             // Boolean
  "string": "string",       // String
  "int" : 123,              // Long for all non floats are ok but if possible i'd like this to be Integer if it fits, otherwise Long
  "long" : 100000000000000, // Long if Integer cant contain the number...
  "double" : 123.123435,    // all floating point nubmers will just map to Double
  "object" : {              // another HashMap
    ...
  }
  "array" : [               // Array or some collection like ArrayList or LinkedList
    ...
  ]
}
```

The goal is to convert any json **as fast as possible** to java Map (or Array if root of json is array) and then use some accessor methods to access data... and not invent java type for every single possible json structure...

Comment: Can you post an example of your json?

Comment: I'll update question so that you see what i mean... Json can be anything, mostly floating point values which i want in as Double and Strings all in a HashMap (as ordering or sorting does not mean anything here)...

Comment: Any decent JSON parser, properly used, should be able to parse that into Maps and Lists, with the appropriate data types for the primitives.  As to speed, all the JSON parsers claim to be "fast", so you might need to benchmark your favorites.

Comment: @HotLicks for example how do you make GSON or any of your known libs to parse into HashMaps (meaning that you dont care about ordering or sorting)? because it seems to me that most assume that you do care and use LinkedSomething... which is not memory efficient and produces lot of garbage...

Comment: I'm now considering this SAXophone project from OpenHFT where i'll have to implement parsing symbol by symbol...

Comment: I don't see that you should be concerned that a JSON kit returns LinkedHashMap vs HashMap.  The difference in size and performance would be miniscule.  But I'm certain that if you work through the list of 20-30 kits at json.org you will find one that uses HashMap.

Comment: @HotLicks thanks i didnt know all major libs are listed there, but anyway trying out 20 of those is time consuming, i really hope someone already knows what might work here... 

meanwhile i'll do my best with Saxophone... seems this will be the fastest as it is designed for HFT... (and those guys are counting any macrosecond and any byte :)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine with [Jackson Databind](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.fasterxml.jackson.core%7Cjackson-databind%7C2.5.1%7Cbundle) library:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Map.class);
```

The values in the map will be of their corresponding type.
This test passes:

```
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        String jsonString = "{\"bool\": true,"
                + "\"str\":\"strv\","
                + "\"long\": 100000000000000}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(jsonString , Map.class);

        assertEquals(Long.class, map.get("long").getClass());
        assertEquals(Boolean.class, map.get("bool").getClass());
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code snippet and it works exactly as Gson except it uses LinkedHashMap instead of LinkedTreeMap... and all values are strings or Booleans...

Comment: are you sure jackson does this? maybe there is a way to configure them to have that behaviour trough builders or something...

Comment: @Vach -- Maybe you should show us a small piece of your REAL data.

Comment: @HotLicks not sure that makes sence but here you go http://i.imgur.com/AWQxp00.png

Comment: All i need is data structure that only consists of primitive wrappers, string, Hashmap or Linkedlist...

Comment: pretty much any other lib adds so many stuff i dont need that i think its worth to parse json manually :(

Comment: @Vach - Note that the numbers directly in the "data" object are strings.  You have to drill down into "24hr" and "last_trade" to get "numbers" (that will likely be represented as Double and Long objects).

Comment: @HotLicks thats a good note, i know about it, those will be handled manually like, code will know that there will be no date object, it will parse using previously instantiated DateFormatter and get Date from string... but general problem here is what i've described... :)

Comment: @Vach Added a unit test. Is there a json on which it fails for you? If so, please add it to your question

Comment: @metrimer http://i.imgur.com/rbSH76p.png here is what i did...
what jackson or gson do covers probably most usecases, i'm not surpirzed they do like this... but i hoped they would actually provide option to configure them... so that if one does not need treemap why shall he have one?

Comment: @Vach In your json `"id": "466"` the value is a *string*. That's why it ends up a string in the map. Remove the quotes to make it: `"id":466`

Comment: @metrimer thanks, i guess thats the case for gson too :) (answer accepted)

Comment: @Vach - Visit json.org again and study the syntax.  The value of "id" is a string, since it's enclosed in quotes.  Yes, the parser is using a LinkedHashMap, but that what that parser does (because lots of stupid JSON users -- especially Java ones -- demand it).  Other parsers won't.  Most people using a parser reasonably will never notice the difference -- the only way to find one that doesn't use LinkedHashMap is to find one that stupid JSON users have complained about.  Or test them yourself.